# How to do a search in Django correctly?

Tags: python, django, search

I'm quite new to Django. And I have a problem with the search implementation. I looked through quite a lot of material and tried many options, but nothing came out. I want to implement a search so that it searches for the product model. Can you help me with this problem?

**views.py**

```
def indexView(ListView):
model = index

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.GET.get('search'):
        queryset = queryset.filter(model=self.request.GET['search'])
    return queryset

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) | {'index_filter': IndexFilter(self.request.GET)}

return render(ListView, 'index_list.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class index(models.Model):
    BRAND = [
        ('apple', 'apple'),
        ('samsung', 'samsung'),
        ('huawei', 'huawei'),
    ]
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BRAND)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='None')
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=0.0)
    image = models.URLField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', indexViews, name='index')
]
```

**index_list.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'index' %}">
        {{ index_filters.form }}
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" name="search" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {% for indexViews in index_filters.qs %}
        <img src="{{ indexViews.image }}" width="200" alt="">
        <div class="product">
            Model: {{ indexViews.model }}
            <br>Category: {{ indexViews.brand }}
            <br>Price: {{ indexViews.price }} $
            <br>----------------------------------
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**forms.py**

```
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineCheckboxes
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout
from django import forms
from .models import *

class IndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = index
        fields = {'brand'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to read about Django-GCBV ListView.
More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#listview-working-with-many-django-objects

in your case:

```
def indexView(ListView):
    model = Index
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('search'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(model=self.request.GET['search'])
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) | {'index_filter': IndexFilter(self.request.GET)}
```

template should be named index_list.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'index' %}">
        {{ index_filter }}
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" name="search" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {% for indexViews in object_list %}
        <img src="{{ indexViews.image }}" width="200" alt="">
        <div class="product">
            Model: {{ indexViews.model }}
            <br>Category: {{ indexViews.brand }}
            <br>Price: {{ indexViews.price }} $
            <br>----------------------------------
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

But i dont understand, why you need form.

Comment: I added the code forms.py . But now I don't have my products displayed :-) I tried to output them via contact, but I got an error. I read the documentation that you sent me above. I didn't quite understand everything in it, but I need to understand Django-GCBV a little more